# All flavor of Ubuntu 15.04 goes to sleep on login screen?

Tags: suspend, login-screen

After boot and the login screen is showing up, my laptop immediately goes into sleep even when I'm typing my password. I have used Ubuntu since 2010 on this machine, this is the first version that behaves this way. Is there something fundamentally changed in this release? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then Add the options acpi=off apm=off to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Then run:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot your computer.